# url routing with PHP and .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2

I want to use the MVC pattern to divide my logic, from the presentation and the data.

Well, i've been searching for i while. But the truth is that i don't even know what to search.

I'm trying to setup a MVC Framework in php. I'm following a tutorial on youtube, and i'm stuck at the routing point.

I've read a LOT of guides, and every single one teaches things in different ways, creating only more confusion.

The point is this:

i have a .htaccess file that contains some directives (but the problem is that i don't know what all those directives means. I've never understood the htaccess logic)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

#I think this sets the base url of the site?
RewriteBase /~caiuscitiriga/mvc/public

#What does this mean??
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#AND THIS?!
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And then i have these php scripts:

#### Index.php

```
<?php

require_once '../app/init.php';

$app = new App();
```

#### init.php

```
<?php

require_once 'core/App.php';
require_once 'core/Controller.php';
```

#### App.php

Don't ask me why i used ***filter_var*** and ***rtrim***. Because is exactly what i want to figure out. As i said before, this code isn't mine. I'm sure that the trick it's exactly in .htacess and App.php but i don't understand the logic

```
class App{


    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];


    public function __construct()
    {
        print_r($this->parseUrl());
    }

    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['url']))
        {
            return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Controller.php

```
<?php

class Controller{

}
```

#### home.php

```
<?php

class Home extends Controller{

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'home/index';
    }
}
```

If i pass this url: ***localhost/~caiuscitiriga/mvc/public/home/index/maxine***
I GET THIS: Array ( [0] => home [1] => index [2] => maxine )

WHY?!!? I mean, it's correct. But why??

Comment: why do i get that array in that specific way? What does the htacess to the url?

And after that, what does exactly php before returning the url?

Comment: Citation: "I've never understood the htaccess logic"... Then I suggest you start reading the documentation instead of "LOTS of guides".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I read the above as, if the request is not a directory, and not a file, then take the path and pass it to index.php internally with the url attribute as the path.

So now

```
//example.com/big/bad/mamma
```

maps to

```
 //example.com/index.php?url=big/bad/mamma
```

You could call the script as above if you want.

Then your parse url is taking the value of url ('big/bad/mamma'), removing a trailing slash if there is one.  And then splitting the string wherever it encounters a forward slash.  So you end up with three parts.  Which is what you have in your array.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php):

The FILTER_SANITIZE_URL filter will remove all characters except letters, digits and $-_.+!*'(),{}|\^~[]`<>#%";/?:@&=.

But break it down if you want to understand the pieces:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
var_dump($url);
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
var_dump($url);
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
var_dump($url);
$url = explode('/', $url);
var_dump($url);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! That's exactly the answer i was looking for! Now i have a little curious question.  Is filter_var really necessary? I've tried to pass urls with and without trailing slashes with the $url = filter_var(...) line commented and things were still working well...

Comment: i would like to upvote your answer but i have only 3 points D: