# use .htaccess to complete document extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my last server I had a .htaccess file that completed the urls without redirecting, I didn't quite understand how this was configured, but I am sure it was in the .htaccess file.
All the documentations I read until now only handle one file extension to be replaced (.htm gets redirected to .html).

Lets say I have following files on my server:

```
0:   001.jpg
1:   002.jpg
2:   002.png
3:   staff.php
```

when I request `example.com/001` file 0 gets displayed, in my searchbar is no extension to be seen
when I request `example.com/002` I get the errorcode 404, since there are 2 files starting with "002"
when I request `example.com/002.j` I get the image 1
when I request `example.com/staff` I get the output of the staff.php

How can I let .htaccess do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981045/url-routing-with-php-and-htaccess Does this answer your question?

Comment: @lorikku I don't see how this would complete any file extension. Or did I miss something?