# How can I call the page in the directory named views when the button is pressed? PHP Router

Tags: php

I want to dynamically call the page in the view index when pressed, how can I do it?

index.php a tags

```
<div class="menu-item"><a href="">Contact</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="">Send Message</a></div>
```

routes.php

```
get('/', 'index.php');

get('/contact', 'views/contact.php');

get('/message', 'views/message.php');
```

router.php

```
function any($route, $path_to_include){ route($route, 
$path_to_include); }
function route($route, $path_to_include){

$ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
if($route == "/"){
    include_once("$ROOT/$path_to_include");
    exit();
}

$request_url = filter_var($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 
FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$request_url = rtrim($request_url, '/');
$request_url = strtok($request_url, '?');
$route_parts = explode('/', $route);
$request_url_parts = explode('/', $request_url);
array_shift($route_parts);
array_shift($request_url_parts);
if( $route_parts[0] == '' && count($request_url_parts) == 0 ){
    include_once("$ROOT/$path_to_include");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Hi abraham, can you provide some code to can help you!, regardss

Comment: I used a php router library, do you think it's ok? 

Comment: In my personal opinion of working with something like this is using the switch statment on the index.php, but my idea is more limitated and is not the ideal if you are working with large size websites. its more like for just `/contact`,`/about`,etc with limitated options.
You can check this question [URL ROUTIN WITH PHP AND .HTACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981045/url-routing-with-php-and-htaccess/34981348), i think you are trying to use the Python Flask MVC

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will use switch case 

Answer (score 0):

You can set name for each route .
i didn't see your routers code so i can't say my opinion surly .
but you can keep your routes in an array and set a name for each route . then write a function that by the name of a route can find it's url

Comment: I use a php router library, but I couldn't make the page call.