# How can I Rewrite Query String to Path and remove %20 in url with dash (-)?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite this URL - `http://127.0.0.1/english-hindi/define.php?term=abatement%20order`  to this URL - `http://127.0.0.1/abatement-order` using rewrite rule in .htaccess file.

I want to rewrite path of the URL and remove `%20` or whitespace with a dash (-)

Now, after adding this rule in .htaccess -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /english-hindi/define.php?term=$1 [L]
```

I can successfully access it through this - `http://127.0.0.1/abatement%20order`
but still after trying different snippets from internet i am unable to replace %20 from URL with dash (-). Please help

Comment: There's two parts to this. First, you must first write the URL how you want it to be written, so it will be your responsibility in PHP to replace spaces or whatever with dashes. If you do this today, these links will obviously 404 so the second part is instructing the server to send all potential 404 requests to PHP. You can do this in [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981348/231316), but generally you can search for "php router".

Comment: Kindly do add your tried .htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: "rewrite / url-rewriting" - Don't you mean "redirect" (not url-rewriting)? Do you only need to _redirect_ this specific URL, or are you after a more general solution?

Comment: I want to "redirect" all URL and more general solution